# error pops up when rendering table "DataTables warning"

Tags: php, mysqli

i have this code that will display the items perfectly but having a error pop up that i have to click "OK" too view the page

i have searched the web and from what i understand this has something to do with that the header table has more column than the data itself, i have tried to troubleshot this and got nowhere fast as i am a novice (noob) :/

if anyone can shed some light on this it would be great! :)

---

The Error

---

```
DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter '0' 
from the data source for row 0
```

---

My Code

---

```
<?php
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

//query all records from the database
$query = "select * from repair_jobs";

//execute the query
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

//get number of rows returned
$num_results = $result->num_rows;

//this will link us to our add.php to create new record
if( $num_results > 0){ //it means there's already a database record

    //start table
    //creating our table heading
    echo "<table id='example' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='display' >";
    echo "<thead><tr>";
        echo "<th>Client</th>";
        echo "<th>Type</th>";
        echo "<th>Labour</th>";
        echo "<th>ourcosts</th>";
    echo "</thead></tr><tbody><tr class=\"gradeX\">";

    //loop to show each records
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            //extract row
            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
            //just $firstname only
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$client}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$type}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$labour}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$ourcosts}</td>";
                                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";//end table

}else{
    //if database table is empty
    echo "No records found.";
}

//disconnect from database
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

it displays ok but this error puzzling me.

Comment: why do you think this code is related to the error message?

Comment: i did the noob thing and Google'd it.... why what could it be? :/